# How do i setup POSTMAN with nested formdata so that i can execute a collection file?

Tags: postman-collection-runner

The examples given by postman team https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files

However, in my situation, i don't have a simple flat file as their example provides. I have a nested data structure. I wanted to know how I can prepare the form data in a nested manner so that the data file is correctly searched and replaced.

Ex:

```
Name:{{Name}}
Age:{{age}}    
addressId:{{addressId}}
addressName:{{addressName}}
addressLine1:{{addressLine1}}
```

---- following is what I'm unsure about on how to indicate the remaining form data as it is an array of addresses. It will not vary in the number of addresses, but is a child of the above.
 my tought was

```
Addresses:
[
addressId:{{addressId}}
addressName:{{addressName}}
addressLine1:{{addressLine1}}
]
```

This form data will be used to load multiple individuals with their addresses reading of a data file with 300 records. Sample datafile structure below:

> [{
>       id:1
>       Name:user1,
>       Age:34,
>       Addresses:
>       [
>       {addressId:1001
>       addressName:home,
>       addressLine1:123 XYZ St}
>       ] },
>
> ```
> id:2
> Name:user2,
> Age:35,
> Addresses:
> [
> {addressId:1002
> addressName:home,
> addressLine1:124 XYZ St}
>
> ]
> ```
>
> }, {
>       id:3
>       Name:user3,
>       Age:34,
>       Addresses:
>       [
>       {addressId:1003
>       addressName:home,
>       addressLine1:125 XYZ St}
>       ]
>
> }]

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is construct the request body in the format you require using the placeholder `{{...}}` syntax.

In the data file use those same names in either a CSV or a JSON file and assign the values that you require. When the collection is run, it will replace the variables in the request.

```
[
    {
      "addressOne": "blah road",
      "addressTwo": "blah avenue",
      "addressThree": "blah street"
    }
]
```

If those `keys` were the placeholders in your request body, then those `values` will be used as the data set when the collection is run.

Comment: i have {{id}} : null both in parent and child object. The {{id}} is different an is intended to be different. Would postman get confused with the id, would this cause a problem? At present, i get a 415 error trying to process this nested JSON not sure why.

Comment: Restructing the way i look at the body
 {
  "name": {{name}},
  "age": {{age}},
  "addressParams":[
  {
   "addressLn1": {{addressLn1}},
   "addressLn2": {{addressLn2}},
   "addressLn3": {{addressLn3}}
  }
  ]
 }

Comment: Can you extend and update your question with this new information - writing different bits of code in the comment is difficult to read. Back up what you’re saying by attaching screen shots too, it helps bring the written information to life and also helps visualise the problem. more.